# Rails - how put javascript variable into erb code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've seen some similar question, but still don't know how achieve my goal.
I want to do that thing:

1. Display modal with products represented by divs.
2. User choose some products (I add .active class to chosen products)
3. Then I use jQuery to make array of chosen products ids.
4. In the end I want to create div for each product, which will be include some informations about this product from database. I'm using js .append() to do it. And here is a problem.

This code is in my script tag in proper view.

```
    var chosen_products_array;

    $('.product-to-choose').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass("visible");
    });

    $('#chosen-products-confirm').click(function() {
        var chosen_products = $('.product-to-choose.active');
        chosen_products_array = jQuery.makeArray( chosen_products );
    });

    $('#confirm').click(function() {

        var textToInsert = '<div><h4>Products:</h4>';
        $.each(chosen_products_array, function(count, item) {
            var id = $(item).attr('id').substr(8); // id is product_number
            textToInsert += '<div><li name="chosen-product"> <%= current_user.products.find(' + id +').name %></li></div>';
        });
        textToInsert += '</div>';
        $('#div-example').append(textToInsert);
    });
```

My controller create action:

```
def create
@meal = current_user.meals.build(meal_params)
if @meal.save
  current_user.type_tags.each do |type_tag|
    key = "type#{type_tag.id}"
    if params[key]
      @meal.type_tags << type_tag # zapis do bazy danych
    end
  end
  flash[:success] = "Create new meal!"
  redirect_to meals_path
else
  #render 'meals/new'
end
```

end

This line generates error:

```
textToInsert += '<div><li name="chosen-product"> <%= current_user.products.find(' + id +').name %></li></div>';
```

Error:

```
Couldn't find Product with 'id'=+id+ [WHERE "products"."user_id" = ?]
```

I know there is a problem in passing js variables to rails erb, but how can I solve it in this case? I tried with gon too.

In my controller, I added:

```
gon.products = current_user.products
```

and then try

```
alert(gon.products)
```

it's ok - array of objects, but when I try

```
alert(gon.products.find(1))
```

it doesn't work.

Have you got any idea how can I put this javascript id variable to erb code? Or maybe is any different solution?

Comment: Gon is for actually passing data for JS from your controller. You could try using capture block for capturing the JS variable and parsing as a Rails variable. Move textToInsert to your controller and trigger for each product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best would be to add a remote form (it may be hidden) that posts whatever you want (javascript values) and then it is handled by a controller. Then you can render it with js views.

This would probably be the most "rails-like" solution.

Here's some code:

In the routes:

```
resource :my_form, only: :create
```

In the view:

```
<%= form_tag(my_form_path, remote: true, method: :post) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :val %>
<% end %>
```

You alter the `val` dynamically by javascript, and submit the form whenever you want to.

Then, in the controller you have something like this:

```
respond_to :js

def create
  # do something with params['val']
  @my_val = params['val']
end
```

And you would also add create.js.erb view, where you could add some javascript that can use any of the instance variables created in the controller.

```
//create.js.erb
$('#someElement').html('<%= @my_val %>');
```

Let me stress if it is not clear, the form is **remote** (ajax), so it is sent in the background and the page is not reloaded.

When the browser receives the response, it may contain any javascript you decide to render (the contents of create.js.erb), and then the browser executes that javascript.

So, you can add there any jquery commands with arguments that you changed dynamically by rails, or you could also render html partials and replace any elements with them, like this:

```
//create.js.erb
$('#my_id').html('<%= j(render partial: 'my_form/_some_partial.html.erb', locals: { my_val: @my_val }) %>');
```

More details on [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

---

UPDATE

Another, inferior but simpler to implement solution would be to always render all products, but have them hidden initially, and then show them by jQuery on demand. You would just need to add appropriate css classes or data attributes to those products, as well as the links you use to select them.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great. I'm really not familiar with Ajax and coffee scripts

Comment: I added some code, please let me know if it is clear enough.

Comment: I'm not sure if I accented it. Idea is that: these divs should be in the same view as pop-up(modal). I don't know if it's matter for you.

Comment: the form is remote, so the page shown in the browser is not reloaded; when the js view is rendered, you still have access to everything previously shown, including the modal.

Comment: Is it important that these generated divs will be in meals/new.html.erb ( so in the view for a new meal generated by another form_tag)? form_tag inside form_tag, is it ok?

Comment: What should be my_path?

Comment: you need to add a new route to routes; I will update the answer.

Comment: It should be in the same controller (Meals)? I've already have create action there which is responsible for create a new meal. How can I accommodate it?

Comment: I saw, but I don't understand how can it work with two create action. Sorry it's my first time with some Ajax and .js.erb files. I editted my question (add controller)

Comment: the two create actions have nothing to do with each other. The one I added as an example is just a means to pass some value from javascript to rails, and this form can be anywhere in the page (since it is hidden).

Comment: ok, I'll try to make it simple and use your code as an example: so, when #confirm is clicked, you want to alter content of some html elements on the page. That is the point at which you would want to submit the hidden form, and pass the selector and the content. Then, you add this values to the instance variables in the controller, and you move all the code you currently have in `$('#confirm').click()` to `create.js.erb`, you just make the selector and the content dynamic, by using the instance variables.

Comment: I really appreciate your engagement. And I very want to understand it, I hope it will be in a while. Could you tell me how can I submit this hidden form? I can assign something like this: $('#val').html('<p>'+id+'</p>'); after clicked #confirm. But what next?

Comment: first, you assign a value to the input like this: $('#val').val('<p>'+id+'</p>') not with html(); and you can submit a form with $('form-selector').submit(). Form-selector is either id or css class you assigned to that form. Guiding you through these basics is out of scope for this question, and we can't continue much longer adding to this comment thread. Please check my earlier update to the answer (at the bottom), perhaps that will be easier to implement.

Comment: Your explanation was very good, thanks. I think I must read much more about Ajax, maybe then I can be implement it in right way. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `erb` code is evaluated on the server before the browser even fetches the javascript file, so it doesn't make sense to use this way. It's recommended that you only use `erb` in your javascript for simple things like `asset_path`

Comment: I wrote that I know about it. But how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think first make your model visible to the browser as js variable(json object) . Some thing like below at the end of your view file(below is the haml syntax):

```
:javascript

   var userProducts        = #{@current_user.products.to_json};
```

Then use it in javascript expression